# Is it possible to select all events in my city where most attendees are within my age range?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using facebook graph API, is it possible to make a search that would return a list of all events in my city, where most (say >50%) of the attendees are within my age range (say born between 1995-2000?)

Comment: no, of course not. you cannot even get a list of events by city, there is only a workaround > getting pages by location and getting events of those pages.

Answer (score 0):

## No, you can't!

What you could do is, fetch all the events in the city, do a loop and check the data you need. I haven't tried to fetch attendees information but i think it is impossible until the user has approved your app.

But @luschn was wrong here. You actually can search events by city.
With a simple graph api search like this: search?q=cityname&type=event
It will search all the event names with that city name in it.

But keep in mind that not all the events are displayed there. You could also do what @luschn recommended but it will take a lot of time to go through all the pages and their events.

If you're trying to build an app that would show nearest events then it's pointless. Theres one website (https://www.minek.ee/tartu). It's in my mother tongue but you can use the search to search events outside of Estonia. I bet that this website uses the same tactic to fetch the events but they are doing the fetching in background while displaying you all the fetched events one by one.

Still, this app doesn't have much traffic so i think there's no point to build anything like this because people really aren't interested in this. I know that i shouldn't give out opinions but i'm pretty sure that building this is just waste of time. Why?? Because i've already built one and it wasn't worth the time.

Comment: You can only search events by name. Yes, that will give you events that happen to have the city in the name - but it does not give you all events for that city.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for pointing it out, i forgot to mention it. I edited my answer